# Using map with a list of years Parameter got 'value' is required. Error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using the following script to try to export some calculated areas for year with a list, but I get the following error

Feature collection (error) `value` is required

```
// Cargar loss 
var hansen = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2022_v1_10');

// Load a FeatureCollection from a table dataset: 'RESOLVE' ecoregions.
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');

//ECO_ID: 569
//ECO_NAME: Dry Chaco
var roi_fc = ecoregions
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ECO_ID', 569) // 
  );

// Convertir la FeatureCollection en un objeto Geometry
var roi = roi_fc.geometry();

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1');

// Definir una función para calcular las áreas para un año dado
function calculateAreas(year1) {
  var year = ee.Number(year1).toInt();
  //year = ee.Number(year).toInt();

  var modis_filtered = modis.filterDate(year.format().cat('-01-01'), year.format().cat('-12-31'));

  modis_filtered = modis_filtered.map(function(img) {return img.clip(roi)});
  
  var modis_fire = modis_filtered.select('BurnDate').reduce(ee.Reducer.max(), 16).gt(0);
  //Map.addLayer(modis_fire.updateMask(modis_fire), {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'Fuego ' + yeari.format());

  //var loss = hansen.select('loss');
  //var fire_deforestation = modis_fire.and(loss);
  var hansen_resampled = hansen.select('lossyear')
  var loss_actual = year - 2000;                        // Año actual

  var loss = hansen_resampled.lt(loss_actual);    // Años previos

  var fire_deforestation = modis_fire.and(loss);

  var modis_projection = modis.first().select('BurnDate').projection();
  var modis_scale = modis_projection.nominalScale();

  // deforested el año anterior al actual
  var deforested_burned_area = ee.Number(fire_deforestation.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);

  var deforested_area = ee.Number(loss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('loss')).divide(1e6);


  // Calcular el área total quemada pero no deforestada en km²
  var burned_not_deforested_area = ee.Number(modis_fire.and(loss.not()).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);


  // Calcular el área total quemada en km²
  var burned_area = ee.Number(modis_fire.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);


  // Crear un diccionario con los resultados para el año especificado
  return {
    year: year,
    deforested_area: deforested_area,
    deforested_burned_area: deforested_burned_area,
    burned_not_deforested_area: burned_not_deforested_area,
    burned_area: burned_area

  };
}

// Generar una lista de años desde el 2001 al 2022
var years = ee.List.sequence(2001,2022);
// Calcular las áreas para cada año de la lista
var results = years.map(calculateAreas);

// Convertir la lista de resultados en una FeatureCollection
var results_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(results.map(function(result) {
   return ee.Feature(null, result);
}));

print(results_fc, "results_fc")

// Exportar la FeatureCollection a un archivo CSV en Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: results_fc,
   description: 'BurnedAndDeforestedAmazon',
   fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because of the following two lines:

```
 var loss_actual = year - 2000;                        // Año actual

 var loss = hansen_resampled.lt(loss_actual);    // Años previos
```

This can be fixed as follows. Observe that you have to use GEE methods and rename adequately loss images.

```
  var loss_actual = year.subtract(2000);                        // Año actual

  var loss = hansen_resampled.lt(loss_actual).rename('loss');    // Años previos
```

So, [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6bb9a10dc3ba613f56bed7c7782b8e08) looks as follows:

```
// Cargar loss 
var hansen = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2022_v1_10');

// Load a FeatureCollection from a table dataset: 'RESOLVE' ecoregions.
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');

//ECO_ID: 569
//ECO_NAME: Dry Chaco
var roi_fc = ecoregions
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ECO_ID', 569) // 
  );

// Convertir la FeatureCollection en un objeto Geometry
var roi = roi_fc.geometry();

var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1');

// Definir una función para calcular las áreas para un año dado
function calculateAreas(year1) {
  
  var year = ee.Number(year1).toInt();
  //year = ee.Number(year).toInt();

  var modis_filtered = modis.filterDate(year.format().cat('-01-01'), year.format().cat('-12-31'));

  modis_filtered = modis_filtered.map(function(img) {return img.clip(roi)});
  
  var modis_fire = modis_filtered.select('BurnDate').reduce(ee.Reducer.max(), 16).gt(0);
  //Map.addLayer(modis_fire.updateMask(modis_fire), {palette: 'FF0000'}, 'Fuego ' + yeari.format());

  //var loss = hansen.select('loss');
  //var fire_deforestation = modis_fire.and(loss);
  var hansen_resampled = hansen.select('lossyear');
  var loss_actual = year.subtract(2000);                        // Año actual

  var loss = hansen_resampled.lt(loss_actual).rename('loss');    // Años previos

  var fire_deforestation = modis_fire.and(loss);

  var modis_projection = modis.first().select('BurnDate').projection();
  var modis_scale = modis_projection.nominalScale();

  // deforested el año anterior al actual
  var deforested_burned_area = ee.Number(fire_deforestation.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);

  var deforested_area = ee.Number(loss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('loss')).divide(1e6);


  // Calcular el área total quemada pero no deforestada en km²
  var burned_not_deforested_area = ee.Number(modis_fire.and(loss.not()).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);


  // Calcular el área total quemada en km²
  var burned_area = ee.Number(modis_fire.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: modis_scale,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).get('BurnDate_max')).divide(1e6);

  
  // Crear un diccionario con los resultados para el año especificado
  return {
    year: year,
    deforested_area: deforested_area,
    deforested_burned_area: deforested_burned_area,
    burned_not_deforested_area: burned_not_deforested_area,
    burned_area: burned_area

  };
  
  //return ee.Algorithms.If(deforested_area, deforested_area, 0);
  
}

// Generar una lista de años desde el 2001 al 2022
var years = ee.List.sequence(2001,2022);
// Calcular las áreas para cada año de la lista
var results = years.map(calculateAreas);

//print(results);

// Convertir la lista de resultados en una FeatureCollection
var results_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(results.map(function(result) {
   return ee.Feature(null, result);
}));

print("results_fc", results_fc);

// Exportar la FeatureCollection a un archivo CSV en Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: results_fc,
   description: 'BurnedAndDeforestedAmazon',
   fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

After running above code at GEE code editor, I got following CSV file with following information: year, deforested_area, deforested_burned_area, burned_not_deforested_area and burned_area.

[image]